# Scrbook: fixing indentation of footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indentation, scrbook

I would like **every** line of a footnote to have the same indentation:

[image]

So "mi et neque [...]" should have the same indentation as "Lorem" (I'd like to achieve this by shifting "mi" to the left). Any way to achieve this?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    Test\footnote{\blindtext}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use KOMA-Script command `\deffootnote` to format the footnote:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
\begin{document}
Test\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Explanation:**

The syntax of `\deffootnote` is

`\deffootnote[mark width ]{indent }{parindent }{definition}`

The default settings are

`\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}`

If the indentiation of the second etc. lines should be the same as the mark width in the first line you can use

`\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}`

or shorter

`\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}`